What is the opt column in iptables -L?
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

opt's column is always --. Can anyone explain this column and provide an example where it has any other value, and in which cases it gets all different possible values whichever they are? And most importantly, where can I find more information about this? I Googled left and right and found nothing.
